# asp:dropdown menu not selecting correct list item after data bind

Tags: c#, data-binding, webforms

I have some dropdowns that are I've built an incrementer function for rather than generating all of the options by hand.

```
public static List<int> Incrementor(int startValue, int maxValue, int increment)
{
    var list = new List<int>();
    for (int i = startValue; i <= maxValue; i += increment)
    {
        list.Add(i);
    }
    return list;
}
```

This gets called on `Page_Load`

```
ddlMonths.DataSource = Incrementor(0, 12, 1);
ddlHOA.DataSource = Incrementor(0, 500, 50);
ddlRemodel.DataSource = Incrementor(0, 80, 5);
ddlUtilities.DataSource = Incrementor(0, 500, 100);

ddlMonths.DataBind();
ddlHOA.DataBind();
ddlRemodel.DataBind();
ddlUtilities.DataBind();
```

After I retrieve the object from the database, I'm getting the correct values, however, when I try to have the dropdowns select the correct value it always selects `0`. Do you see the error in my code?

```
// If there is an offer fill out the forms
If (offer != null)
{
    ddlRemodel.SelectedValue = offer.RemodelRate.ToString();
    ddlMonths.SelectedValue = offer.MonthsHeld.ToString();
    ddlHOA.SelectedValue = (offer.HOADues * 2).ToString();
    ddlUtilities.SelectedValue = offer.Utilities.ToString();
}
```

Comment: So you load them in `Page_Load`(hopefully with `if(!IsPostBack)`-Check). But when do you set the `SelectedValue`s? Are the `DropDown`'s declared in the aspx-page or added dynamically?

Comment: I am doing `!IsPostBack` check On the aspx-page the DDLs are getting loaded like `<asp:DropDownList runat="server" class="input-xlarge" ID="ddlRemodel" ClientIDMode="Static"></asp:DropDownList>` Oddly the Months part works fine, but the other 3 dont

Comment: Try moving your `Page_Load` code into `Page_Init`.

Comment: in the database the months data is an integer, the other 3 are decimals, not sure if that is causing an issue

Comment: @JonHarding In that case, I'd try converting all the items to `int` before setting them to the `.SelectedValue`

Comment: converting to ints did the trick. Seems odd to have to convert to Int before converting to string

Answer (score 0):

For your code you have shown that gets called on page load, only do so if IsPostBack is false. Otherwise you will reset the controls. They don't need the data again, it's in viewstate now.

Comment: The dropdowns would need to get loaded each time whether it's a postback or not so that the dropdowns have options to select.